# Items being added into sorted list in wrong order

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I'm adding a list of values into a sorted list. The problem is that it's not adding the data into my sorted list correctly.

```
public static void newList(List<string> oldList, List<string> headers)
    {
        var noHeaders = removeHeaders(oldList, headers);

        SortedList<string, string> newList = new SortedList<string, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count; i++)
        {
            newList.Add(headers[i], "placeholder");
        }

            //foreach (string header in headers)
            //{
            //    newList.Add(header, "placeholder");
            //}
```

Above is a snippet of my code, I've tried all different kinds of loops with the same result.

The data from the "headers" list looks like this:

```
[0]Value1
[1]Value2
[2]Value3
[3]Value4
```

When I look at the same data once it's been added into the sorted list it looks like this:

```
[0]Value2
[1]Value1
[2]Value4
[3]Value3
```

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening so that I can fix it? I've searched around for a bit but couldn't find anything helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming your keys in the SortedList are in alphabetical order given that you are using a **Sorted**List. If you don't want to achieve this ordering, you're probably better off using a Dictionary.

Comment: You have to pass it a comparer method.  It doesn't know how to put them in order.  See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: SortedList sorts ***by key*** not by insertion order. Are you sure this is what you actually want to happen? How do you hope to use your data structure when you've built it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the entries of the list are sorted with respect to the *keys*, not the *values*; this means that the order you observe depends on the values provided in `headers` and the *values* as such are not sorted.